# For loop in a leaflet bindpop up

Tags: javascript, django, leaflet, mapbox

I want to display multiple entries that are in a list on a leaflet popup.

```
marker.bindPopup('<div class = "content"><p>{% for i in lists %}'+{{i}}+'{% endfor %}</p></div>');
```

This would not work. How should I go about it? Thanks!

Comment: "This would not work": give more detail. _How_ does it not work? An error message? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using some kind of framework, but doing

```
{% for i in lists %}'+{{i}}+'{% endfor %}
```

in a pure JS string won't parsed in a particular way or stuff like this and will just be interpreted as a string.

Do something like this instead :

```
function createHtmlAttributes(list) {
    var response = "<div class = 'content'>";
    for (var prop in list) {
        response += "<p>" + prop + " : " + list[prop] + "</p>";
    }
    response += "</div>";

    return response;
}

marker.bindPopup(createHtmlAttributes(lists));
```

This should do it.